# How do I make Material UI's TextField dropdown selector open with a limited size of items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dropdown

I am currently working on a Sign up Page, whenever a user enters their location, they will be prompted by a dropdown list of items of different countries, however, when the user opens that list, it covers the whole screen. How would I edit Material UI's TextField component to make it only list a certain number of items at a time without scrolling? Like 5 at a time maybe?

Here is the code in question:

```
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import {MenuItem, TextField, InputAdornment } from '@mui/material'
import countryList from 'react-select-country-list'
import AddLocationIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddLocation';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { createUsers } from '../../reducers/usersReducer';

const CountryOfOrigin = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const options = useMemo(() => countryList().getData(), [])

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(createUsers(e.target.value, 'location'))
  }

  return (
      <TextField onChange={changeHandler} select className='users-location-input' required={true} label='Location'  defaultValue='' InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment>
            <AddLocationIcon color='primary'/>
          </InputAdornment>
        )
      }}>
        {options.map(option => {
           return (<MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.label}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>)
        })}
      </TextField>
  )
}

export default CountryOfOrigin
```

Furthermore,

Here are some screenshots showing the current size of the dropdown list when you **open** it:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Try specificing `SelectProps` like `SelectProps={{ sx: { maxHeight: 100 } }}`

Comment: If you use `Menu` instead of `TextField` you will get access to the `paperProps` where you can limit the menu. [Max height Menu](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/#LongMenu.js)

Comment: @Mohammed Is there anyway I can add an Icon to the start of the Menu as well? That is the only reason why I am using Textfield in the first place...

Comment: @user1672994 Only changes the height of the textbox itself versus the dropdown menu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a maxHeight property to the SelectProps of the textfield component. Also, I believe you should rather use an MUI autocomplete if you want autocompletion and dropdown both.

Comment: Only seems to change the height of the textbox itself versus the dropdown menu

Comment: Then maybe you should try to swap out the TextField with a Select component instead, since passing in a maxHeight property to the MenuProps of a Select component will solve your problem. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61686939/material-ui-apply-max-height-to-select-children). Or, you could perhaps make use of the very customizable autocomplete component in MUI.

Comment: Will it allow me to add an icon at start though? Because I want an icon at start. Just like the first image for "Location" in my post...

Comment: I am pretty sure its possible mui autocomplete using some workarounds. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847347/material-ui-autocomplete-add-a-value-to-startadornment) post should help you in doing so.

Comment: For controlling the height of the dropdown part what you want is  `SelectProps={{ MenuProps: { style: { maxHeight: 400, }, }, }}`